what if a new feature is merely the first step to improving an existing process?
Let's suppose that a current process will be greatly improved if the ability to do X existed.
Someone invented a feature that can be added to this process.
This feature alone in the process does not enable the great improvement.
However, this feature enables the process to do X.
If this is the case, can this feature alone be patented?

I don't think it is possible to answer this question in the abstract. When you brush up against the edges of patentability, the details, like the actual claim wording, matter a lot. Even then it can be a coin toss whether such a claim would be held to be valid.

Also, does the feature have any identified/possible/speculative use outside of the given process? If not, what is the point of attempting to patent it in isolation?

@bhuff36 no, the attempt is not to patent this feature in isolation. But rather, to patent the process with this feature. However, leaving out the X.

_Bear: I don't understand. You said the feature enables the process to do X. Do you mean that you want to be silent on this particular utility of the new process? Then your question is basically: if there are multiple possible utilities of an invention, should they all be listed or is it possible/advisable to omit some?

@bhuff36 no, in the spec, it heavily mentions the utility of enabling the process to be able to do X. But doing X is not part of the claim.

It sounds like X is a result of the process. It can be put in the claim optionally using a "whereby" clause. If adding the feature to the process causes X as a result, and X is highly desirable, I would say that the feature does enable X, contrary to your characterization of it. Perhaps I've misunderstood.
